# Editions of Orot - Har Bracha or Yediot Seforim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, abraham-isaac-kook

I am deciding between two editions of Orot by Rav Kook. One edition is from Har Bracha and contains the commentary of Rav Ze'ev Solonovitch. The other is from Yediot Seforim and contains the commentary of Rav Haggai Londin. Is anyone familiar with these editions? Which one would you recommend?